# Google reCAPTCHA not loading and getting console error

Tags: recaptcha

Getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" error while trying to load reCAPTCHA on the login page with Struts 1. The error is occurring in the "recaptcha__en.js" file and specifically references the 'style' property.